# JTextField not appearing in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I have created a game that spawns a image (JLabel) at a random location on the screen. When clicked, the image spawns in a different random location. I now plan to also have text on the screen. I am doing this using a JTextField. The problem is that the JTextField `msg` is not appearing despite it being added using the same method as the JLabel `box`. Can someone explain why it is not spawning in the JFrame?

BoxGame:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BoxGame02 extends JFrame {

    static JLabel box       = new JLabel();
    static JTextField msg   = new JTextField();

    static int min          = 2;
    static int max          = 350;

    static Random random    = new Random();
    static int rand1        = min + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);
    static int rand2        = min + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);
    static int randMessage  = 1   + random.nextInt(10  -  1  + 1);

    public BoxGame02() {
        super("Click the Box!");
        setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/btayl/JavaProjects/Java Game Development/Box Game/BoxGame02/Images/face.png");
        box.setIcon(icon);
        box.setSize(50,50);

        box.setLocation(rand1, rand2);
        add(box);

        msg.setText("Text on Screen");
        msg.setLocation(10, 200);
        add(msg);

        box.setName("box");
        BoxListener clickBox = new BoxListener();

        box.addMouseListener(clickBox);

    }

    class BoxListener extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel l = (JLabel) e.getSource();

            if(l.getName().equals("box"))
                moveBox();
        }
    }
    public void moveBox() {
        System.out.println("Testing!");

        rand1            = min + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);
        rand2            = min + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);
        randMessage      = 1   + random.nextInt(10  -  1  + 1); 

        box.setLocation(rand1, rand2);
        add(box);

        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Window:

```
public class Window {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BoxGame02 frame = new BoxGame02();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `setLayout(null)` does? Try to use a layout manager to see if something changes...

Comment: I set it to null so I can set the exact coordinates. I know it is not  the best method for building programs but I think in this case it works fine.

Comment: `in this case it works fine.` - and what if the random location of the label overlaps the text field? You need to create separate panels. For example, you could add the text field to the PAGE_START of the frame. Then you create a separate panel and add this panel to the CENTER of the frame. Then you add the label to this second panel. Now the random location of the label will never overlap with the text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the JTextField msg is not appearing despite it being added using the same method as the JLabel box.

No you did not use the same method as you did with the label. Look at your code again closely.

What methods did you use on the JLabel?

Now compare the methods used for the JTextField to see what the difference is.

In your "moveBox()" method you don't need to keep adding the box to the panel. You only add the box once. Then you can simple change its location.

You should not be using static variables. The variables should be instance variables for the class.

Comment: I have tried to add `msg` in both the moveBox() and mouseClicked() method and it still doesn't work. Could you provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: @SputnicK, You said the code is the same. So tell me, what methods do you invoke on the "box" variable and what methods do you invoke on the "msg" variable. If you want to use a null layout you need to manage the same properties on each component. This is another reason to use a layout manager.

Comment: Oh I didn't set the size... Welp I'm an idiot. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @SputnicK, Yes. Again it should be the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of the component. You don't know what the size of the text field should be in order to properly display the text. Also, you don't know what the size of your image is. Any time you hard code values you will have a maintenance issue. Even if you want random location of a component you can still use a layout manager. See [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) for a layout to help you out.